# Passing a variable between two functions

Tags: python, tkinter

The following is a piece of code that I have been working on for awhile. I've been able to compile and run the code without error. However, I am having a difficult time with passing a variable from one function to another in my code.

The problem seems to occur after I run `choose()` and create `self.newLists` based on the desired indices. You'll notice that I added `print(self.newLists)` at the end of this function so that I can check to see if it is producing what I want.

The next function, `simplify()`, is where my issue arises. When I try to pass `self.newLists` from the previous function it doesn't seem to produce anything. I also tried printing and/or returning the variable named `answer` but it returns "none". I've been stumbling over this obstacle for awhile without any progress. Below is the code I am working on along with an example of what I want `simplify()` to produce.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

class myFileOpener:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        print()
        self.newLists = ()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Select File", command=self.openfile)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.runButton = Button(frame, text="Run", command=self.combine)
        self.runButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def openfile(self):
        filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
        self.lines = open(filename)
        # print(self.lines.read())

    def choose(self):
        g = self.lines.readlines()
        for line in g:
            matrix = line.split()
            JD = matrix[2]
            mintime = matrix[5]
            maxtime = matrix[7]
            self.newLists = [JD, mintime, maxtime]
            print(self.newLists)

    def simplify(self):
        dates = {}
        for sub in self.newLists:
            date = sub[0]
            if date not in dates:
                dates[date] = []
            dates[date].extend(sub[1])
        answer = []
        for date in sorted(dates):
            answer.append([date] + dates[date])
        return answer

    def combine(self):
        self.choose()
        self.simplify()


root = Tk()
b = myFileOpener(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Example of desired output from `simplify()`:

```
[['2014-158', '20:07:11.881', '20:43:04.546', '20:43:47.447', '21:11:08.997', '21:11:16.697', '21:22:07.717'],
 ['2014-163', '17:12:09.071', '17:38:08.219', '17:38:28.310', '17:59:25.649', '18:05:59.536', '18:09:53.243', '18:13:47.671', '18:16:53.976', '18:20:31.538', '18:23:02.243']]
```

It essentially groups times by certain dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not producing a list of lists. You are *resetting* `self.newLists` each loop iteration, to a single list with 3 elements:

```
for line in g:
    matrix = line.split()
    JD = matrix[2]
    mintime = matrix[5]
    maxtime = matrix[7]
    self.newLists = [JD, mintime, maxtime]
```

You need to instead use `list.append()` to add those 3 elements to a list you set *once*, outside of the loop:

```
self.newLists = []
for line in g:
    matrix = line.split()
    JD = matrix[2]
    mintime = matrix[5]
    maxtime = matrix[7]
    self.newLists.append([JD, mintime, maxtime])
```

Your `simplify` method is adding the *individual characters* of `mintime` to your output lists:

```
for sub in self.newLists:
    date = sub[0]
    if date not in dates:
        dates[date] = []
    dates[date].extend(sub[1])
```

You want to use `list.append()` there, not `list.extend()`. That loop can be simplified using `dict.setdefault()` rather than test for the key manually:

```
for date, mintime, maxtime in self.newLists:
    dates.setdefault(date, []).append(mintime)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix my issue. What I initially started with seems to produce the result I want (i.e. the order and necessary info). Appending the 3 elements to a lists seems to create a redundancy of one particular list.

Comment: @NeophyteAK: the line `dates[date].extend(sub[1])` looks wrong; are you sure you didn't mean to use `dates[date].append(sub[1])` instead? `list.extend()` will take the individual elements of `sub[1]` (a string) and add them one by one to the list.

Comment: I believe I have that right. I have another py file that I created to test that function and it seemed to work. However, there is still no result being produced by the def simplify(self) function. So I think the variable either isn't being created correctly in the previous function  def choose(self) or it isn't getting passed to the def simplify(function) entirely. What are your thoughts? I have an example of the original file containing the text which is used in the first function. Would that provide more insight?

Comment: @NeophyteAK: you are not doing anything with the return value; `self.simplify()` is called without the return value being put to any use.

Comment: @NeophyteAK: in any case, I can easily reconstruct enough of your original file to test the code and it works as designed with my changes. You simply need to *do* something with the return value of `self.simplify()`.

Comment: Ok. I'll rework my code and give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The use of the built-in type dict.setdefault() was a much better solution than what I originally had. It's much easier to understand what is happening and is a better use of python overall.